# JDO PersistenceManager: how can I tell that an object returned by getObjectById has been deleted?

Tags: java, jdo

In my app I have a certain control flow that goes like this:

```
DAO object = persistenceManager.getObjectById(DAO.class, id);

...

persistenceManager.deletePersistent(anotherReferenceToObject);

...

DAO aThirdObjectReference = persistenceManager.getObjectById(DAO.class, id);
```

These are all in different scopes, but the `persistenceManager` references all point to the same `PersistenceManager`.

The problem comes in when the third DAO object turns out to be the same as the second object.  The `PersistenceManager` happily returns the same object that was just deleted, but I need to know it was deleted before I try accessing or changing parts of it!

I don't want to close the pm because it's important for other reasons to keep it open.  Is there any way to tell if an object has been the parameter to `deletePersistent`?

Comment: Tried calling JDOHelper.getObjectState(obj) ?

Comment: No, I had no idea!  This is the answer I was looking for - thanks!  `JDOHelper.getObjectState(object).equals(ObjectState.PERSISTENT_DELETED)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DataNucleus pointed out, I can test for prior deletion with:

```
JDOHelper.getObjectState(object).equals(ObjectState.PERSISTENT_DELETED)
```

This will return true after `object` has been deleted even if the transaction has not been committed and the pm has not been flushed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using PersistenceManager.flush() after you delete the object? Until that is called either programmatically or when the manager is closed, any changes (edits, creations, deletions) will not be committed to the database. Thus, "deleted" objects will be accessible in their original state from when the PersistenceManager was created/last flushed.

Comment: Unfortunately, pm.flush() doesn't have the effect I want.  Even after flush()ing, the object can be retrieved again.  If I begin() and commit() a transaction around the delete, _then_ the object will not be returned.  But... I don't even mind the object being returned.  I just want to know if it's safe to access it!  I could always wrap my attempt in a try/catch JDOUserException, I guess...